# Creating Virtual machines based on size?

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, diskspace

Lets say if i have a server of 500gb of disk space. Suppose, if i have to create 500VM's of each virtual machine of size 50gb. How can I do it?

I was reading across few puzzles and came across this question.

Answer (score 1):

Most VMs will allow you to create dynamic disks.  So you create a dynamic disk of a maximum size (say 10GB), but it only actually uses what is written to the disk (which is generally much less).

Of course if you fill the disk with 10GB of data, then it uses 10GB of real storage.